# Hosting Rails app on Thins, Nginx on a sub uri, behind a reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, reverse-proxy

**Background**

For my work, we have two different networks, the developers network, and the general company network. I need to expose the rails app to both, running under a sub uri so that the people on the general network can get to the app from foo.bar.com/{app_name}, and on the developer network from http://{server_name}.{dev_network}.dev/{app_name}. Sadly, we are not allowed to use Passenger, as this is an enterprise application.

Currently, I have the app running on a sub uri, and able to be accessed from both networks, but I am running into errors. I will list the errors I am seeing, then the nginx config I have created, as well as the rails_app config to work with the sub uri.

**Problems**

- Going to {app_name}/foo/1 - any images on page are being fetched from {app_name}/foo/{app_name}/assets...... This is only happening for the show pages of the RESTful services.
- Refreshing the page, on either network, reloads the page, but removes all styling and js files attached to that page. Going to another link does not effect the styling, except for the issue noted above.

**Configurations**

Nginx
VHost in sites-available, symlinked to sites-enabled.

```
upstream claxon {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name claxon;
    root /var/www;

    location ~* ^/claxon/ {
            alias /var/www/claxon/public;
            proxy_pass http://claxon;
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
            root /var/www/claxon/public/claxon;
    }

    location ^~ /original_user_images/ {
            root /var/www/claxon/public/claxon;
    }
}
```

Rails App

config/initializers/mount_location.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.config.relative_url_root = '/claxon'
end
```

config.ru

```
map Rails.application.config.relative_url_root || '/' do
  run Rails.application
end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
# Configures assets to be compiled under public/claxon/assets
config.assets.prefix = 'claxon/assets'
```

**Additional Details**

- This app is being deployed to the server using capistrano, and the
  current folder is being symlinked to the /var/www/claxon folder.
- This app uses carrierwave for user image uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was to ultimately configure the rails app to server the assets from a 'asset_host'. I set the asset host url to be the same as if connecting to the server from the enterprise network, as the developer network is contained within it, but the enterprise network cannot see the development network. Configuring it this way allows for both networks to receive the assets, and work across a refresh.

This final configuration in the production.rb file is as such.

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://foo.bar.com/claxon/"
```

This allows all assets to be derived from `https://foo.bar.com/claxon/claxon/assets/....`